# How can I send multiple row values in form field with angularJS to web api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I want to insert the multiple row values in angularJS controller via web api

```
<tr ng-repeat="rt in xxtt">

      <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="rt .name" required />
     </td>
    <td>`enter code here`
     <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="rt .email" required />
     </td>
    </tr>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="btnSave()">
    Save
    </button>

$scope.newarray=[];
params = {
            "id": $scope.id

            "nameList": [
                    {
                        "name": $scope.name

                    }
            ]
        }     
angular.forEach($scope.nameList, function (response) {
                    $scope.newarray.push({ name: response.name });
                });
params = JSON.stringify(params);        
        alert(params);
        LoadSvc.LoadData(params).then(function (response) {  
}
```

I can add multiple row values at a time 
How can i send list of array values in angularjs to web api

Comment: Didnt get your question. Do you want to get the response from web api from   and set it to the UI or send data to web api from UI.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your html is invalid that's why your ng-repeat might not be working. You have to wrap `<tr></tr>` in `<table></table>`. Moreover, in order to send data to server via a web api you should use `$http` service. More specifically if you need to *"create"* something new you might use POST method.

For more information you have to take a look at [$http service documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

To conclude your `btnSave()` should make this operation and use `$http` service.

Your finaly code might look something like this.

**Template**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="rt in xxtt">
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="rt.name" required />
      </td>
      <td>`enter code here`
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="rt.email" required />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button class="btn" ng-click="btnSave()">
    Save
  </button>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
 $scope.btnSave = function() {

            /** You have to use your endpoint here **/
      $http.post('some-endpoint.com', $scope.xxtt).then(function(response) {
                    alert("I've posted data successfully");
            },function() {
          alert("I've failed to post data");
      });

  }
```

Here's a [working sample of your code.](https://jsfiddle.net/hng1sbt6/1/)

Comment: I have to insert multiple rows like this params = {
            "name": $scope.name
        } but i have child params  like this params{"email":$scope.email} how to send parent and child response value api via angularjs

Comment: $scope.newarray=[];
params = {
            "id": $scope.id
            
            "nameList": [
                    {
                        "name": $scope.name
                        
                    }
            ]
        }     
angular.forEach($scope.nameList, function (response) {
                    $scope.newarray.push({ name: response.name });
                }); i need insert nameList array into webapi ,how to solve this

Comment: With the http POST method. Check the link at my answer

Comment: Hi ,this is not use for me.

Comment: i used like this params = JSON.stringify(params);        
        alert(params);
        LoadDataService.LoadData(params).then(function (response) {

Comment: Update your question and give more details about the issue you're facing.

Comment: Hi Korte, i have two grid the first grid value insert successfully and second grid value not inserted , i written insert logic in api side, client side using angularjs paramaters ,but second we can add multiple rows  i display some like this 
angular.forEach($scope.nameList, function (response) {
                    $scope.newarray.push({ name: response.name });
                });
params = JSON.stringify(params);        
        alert(params);
        LoadDataSvc.LoadData(params).then(function (response) {  
}